# Redo and Undo for shapes using SurfaceView in android

Tags: android, android-canvas, surfaceview, undo-redo

I am trying to develop an app similar to paint app.

I want allow user to perform **redo** or **undo** operations over `canvas`.
I searched a lot, but dint find any example that explains about redo
and undo operations for Circle, Rectangle etc.
most of the tutorials explain redo and undo for Line.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Try to think as follows centralizes all of your operations (line, circle, square, etc.) through a stack, every time call undo put the action into another stack (redo)

Comment: [HTML5 Canvas tutorial](http://www.codicode.com/art/undo_and_redo_to_the_html5_canvas.aspx) this is a example with a HTML5 canvas try to understand and apply to Android canvas. I have not worked with canvas in android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store every operation in a list, then if you want to undo something just remove the last thing you put into the list. A linkedlist or a stack would work.

Pseudocode

```
Stack<Action> operations=new Stack<Action>();
Stack<Action> redos=new Stack<Action>();
```

Every time user have done something do

```
operations.push(new Action(actiontype,ccoordinates));
```

for undo

```
redoes.push(operations.pop());
```

to redo

```
operations.push(redos.pop());
```

and in your onDraw() method you draw everything thath is in operations...